# Django Exceptions Unregistered Namespace

Tags: python, django, namespaces, django-urls

I am receiving the following error:
"File "C:\Users\odesm\anaconda3\envs\adb3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 83, in reverse
raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'accounts' is not a registered namespace"

I have reviewed similar errors on stack overflow and attempted their solutions but none of them seem applicable. I do not understand in what manner I have failed to register the namespace when it has been specified in the path(include(namespace="")) and I have included the app_name="app_name" in the corresponding url.py file.

base.html (the snippet throwing the error)

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a>
</li>
```

urls.py (under a sitemanger app)

```
app_name = 'sitemanager'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='site-home'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

urls.py (for the accounts app)

```
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(template_name='accounts/signup.html'), name='signup'),
    path('edit/', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(template_name='accounts/update_profile.html'), name='edit'),
    path('<slug:username>/', views.ProfileView.as_view(template_name='accounts/profile.html'), name='profile')
]
```

To me, it appears I have registered the proper namespace but it seems my logic is at fault somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have the urls.py for the accounts app included inside the urls.py for my sitemanager app, I needed to route through sitemanager as well.

Ergo the following

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a>
</li>
```

Needs to become

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'sitemanager:accounts:login' %}">Login</a>
</li>
```